# How to make taext box work without removing cursor from the text box?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke-5

i have a text box, on text_changed event i get one data table which i bind with the grid 
view, but every time i have to move the cursor out then only it feteches the datatable, 
while i want to make this search like if i as i change the character in the text box 
it keep working for all without removing the cursor from the text box, 
any suggestion how can i achieve this. Should i use any java script or what.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "onkeyup" or "onkeydown" rather than the changed event?